# New Golden Ratio Construction with Two Adjacent Squares and Circle. Have you seen anything similar?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, golden-ratio

The below Golden Ratio Construction results in a ratio of PHI (1.6180...) between the blue line and red line, as found in Geogebra.  This seems like a simple construction of the golden ratio, yet so far I have not found anything similar.  If you know of a similar golden ratio construction, please do share!  Thanks!

This Golden Ratio construction is made in the following manner:

1. Draw two adjacent squares Square1 and Square2.
2. Draw a circle with radii equal to the side of the Square, placed at the  corner of Square2 as drawn below.
3. A line passing through the two opposing corners of the two adjacent squares will then define the golden cut in conjunction with the circle, as shown below.  The ratio of segment t to segment s, (or the blue segment to the red segment), is the golden ratio PHI.

[image: New Golden Ratio Construction with Two Adjacent Squares and Circle.]

Has anyone come across anything the same or similar?

And of course trigonometric and geometric proofs of the golden ratio construction are always welcome!

Comment: I haven't seen such a construction before, but just a quick analysis - normalizing the side length of the squares to 1, we have the diagonal of the rectangle with length $\sqrt{1^2+2^2}=\sqrt{5}$, giving the red line length $\sqrt{5}-1$. The diameter of the circle (i.e. the blue line) has length $2$, so the ratio of the blue line to red line is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}-1}=\frac{2\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ as desired.

Comment: @Peter Woolfitt That could be an answer to the [follow on question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797372/new-extremely-simple-golden-ratio-construction-with-two-identical-circles-and-l?noredirect=1#comment3669990_1797372).

Comment: It is very similar to one of the steps for the usual construction of the regular pentagon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon).

Comment: which step @JackD'Aurizio?  could you please be more specific and perhaps even provide a figure or link to a figure or drawing?  thanks! :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Richmond_pentagon_1.PNG

Comment: Thanks @JackD'Aurizio but that seems to be very different from what I drew. :) It is also very different from my newer, simpler construction: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797372/new-extremely-simple-golden-ratio-construction-with-two-identical-circles-and-l

Comment: Difference is in the eye of the beholder. You are constructing $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ through the Pythagorean theorem, just like Richmond.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I did not use the Pythagorean theorem but only simple shapes and geometry, which are very different from the ones in the figure you provided. :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797372/new-extremely-simple-golden-ratio-construction-with-two-identical-circles-and-l

Comment: This is basically the same as https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Construction_of_a_golden_ratio.svg, so that triangle $\triangle DJE$ in this construction serves the same role as triangle $\triangle ABC$ in the other construction. Your construction in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764736/simple-golden-ratio-construction-with-three-lines-and-interesting-implied-circl is more novel, or at least less widely-known.

Comment: whereas the golden ratio is constructed in the long leg of the triangle in the wikipedia example you provide, the golden ratio in my construct is given in not the longer leg of the triangle, but along the segment DM, where the point L is at the golden cut of the segment FD. I asked you to please show how you would establish the golden cut on the longer leg of the triangle in my construct, but you have not done this. This is not a trivial matter. Ergo they are very different constructs.

Answer (score 1):

A similar construction is shown at http://www.goldennumber.net/circles/ in 2006. It just happens to have circles drawn on either side of the center circle, which are not important to the golden ratio point that is created.

Comment: i count three circles used there.  i only use two circles. or in this case a circle and two squares. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your *construction* in this question occurs as a subobject in the construction [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/GoldenRatioMolokach.shtml).  Your particular result does not appear explicitly there, but is produced by projecting Molokach's points $A$, $B$, and $H$ through an unconstructed point interior to the triangle $ACH$.

Your duplicate question, [New, extremely simple golden ratio construction with two identical circles and line. Is there any prior art?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797372/new-extremely-simple-golden-ratio-construction-with-two-identical-circles-and-l), using the two circles construction is equivalent to the left pair of the three circles construction [here](http://www.goldennumber.net/circles/).

Comment: Thanks!  In both cases it seems my constructs are simpler--fewer circles and less complicated objects. :)

Comment: thanks again @EricTowers for your feedback confirming that prior art doesn't exist.  have you ever seen any prior art for the new golden ratio construct i just posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798843/new-very-simple-golden-ratio-construction-incorporating-a-triangle-square-and ? :)