# New, extremely simple golden ratio construction with two identical circles and line. Is there any prior art?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, golden-ratio

This question is different from a previously asked question (linked above) as this golden ratio construction only utilizes two circles and a line, and is thus far simpler than the golden ratio construct in a previously asked question, which uses two squares, a circle, and a line.  Thanks!

Illustrated below, please find a new, extremely simple golden ratio construction with just two identical adjacent circles and a line, wherein the ratio of the red line to the blue line is the golden ratio PHI (1.6180....)
[image]

Is there any prior art?  I have been searching long and hard, but cannot find a similar golden ratio construction.

The simple construction is created as follows.

1. draw two adjacent circles with the same diameter.
2. draw a line from the top of one circle through the center of the second circle.
3. the ratio of line segment h to line segment g (the red segment to the blue segment) will then be exactly PHI or 1.6180....

I've been searching numerous books/online websites/resources for any previous similar constructions.  If you know of any, please do share!  Thanks!

P.S. User @Peter Woolfitt provides a seemingly very nice proof here of a slightly different construction, and any more proofs, either trigonometric or geometric would be weclome! [New Golden Ratio Construction with Two Adjacent Squares and Circle. Have you seen anything similar?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797232/new-golden-ratio-construction-with-two-adjacent-squares-and-circle-have-you-see)

Comment: Yes, the prior art is [the question you asked just two hours ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797232/856).

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, I realized I could make it even simpler with only two circles instead of a square and a circle.  Circles are technically easier to construct, and thus this counts as a "simpler" golden ratio construct.  Thanks!

Comment: @AstrophysicsMath Since the shape on the left isn't even used in the construction, it doesn't matter whether it's a circle or a square. In that sense, this question is a duplicate of your previous one. It would be better if you edited your first question instead.

Comment: How did you know it works before Woolfitt gave his proof?

Comment: @selfawareuser i used geogebra which gave the golden number PHI to fifteeen decimal places. :)

Comment: OP, you should consider submitting this as a MathBit article (under 1 page) to the American Mathematical Monthly.  You should make both circles unit circles for clarity.

Comment: Thanks @Théophile actually yes, the shape is used in the construction as one needs the top of the first circle on the left as a defining point for the line which is cut in the golden ratio.  One also needs the width of the circle as a defining mechanism for where the second circle is placed.  A circle is far easier to construct than the two squares in the other construction.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @vadim123 I am waiting to see if there might be any prior art that anyone has seen.  :)  If not, I will follow your suggestion!

Comment: @Astrophysics Math I haven't checked Woolfitt's proof but if it's valid and this technique is new I think he deserves some credit. I use numerical methods myself but the proof is of course necessary.

Comment: @selfawareuser yes I would like to credit anyone who offers useful proofs, either with their real name or screen name.  feel free to email me @ astrophysicsmath@gmail.com .  thanks! :)  there's another person who goes by Blue who has been very kind with his time and help.

Comment: @selfawareuser , Astrophysics Math The proof is very straight-forward, so no credit would be necessary for me - the interesting part is all in the construction.

Comment: @closevoters While the math may be the same, this question has a slightly different presentation (and presentation here is important), and moreover there is an answer on this one.

Comment: @vadim123 I'd rather recommend http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764736/simple-golden-ratio-construction-with-three-lines-and-interesting-implied-circl (by the same contributor) as material to send to AMM. It is much more distinctively different from other constructions that I've seen.

Comment: @DavidK, why not both?

Comment: Note that that  if you choose 5 units instead of 3 units as radius of first circle you get the comparatively beautiful Pythagorean triplet here, the $ (4,3,5) $ projections for first circle cutting point.So thanks for this golden connection to the Pythagorean triplet !! I am pretty  sure it is not given in text books of elementary trigonometry.

Comment: @vadim123 I think you are right. Actually, both may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks @vadim123!  Here is another golden ratio construct I just posted which you may enjoy: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798843/new-very-simple-golden-ratio-construction-incorporating-a-triangle-square-and

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly more general answer.

Let $R$ and $B$ be the lengths of the red and blue lines respectively. If the radius of the circles is $r$, then we have the equations
$$R=2r$$
since $R$ is the diameter of one of the circles, and
$$B+r=\sqrt{r^2+(2r)^2}=r\sqrt5$$ 
since $B+r$ is the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs of length $r$ and $2r$.

Hence
$$\frac{R}{B}=\frac{2r}{r\sqrt5-r}=\frac{2}{\sqrt5-1}=\frac{2\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}{\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}=\frac{2\left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}=\varphi$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's the proof:
$$6^2+3^2=36+9=45$$
$$\frac{6}{\sqrt{45}-3}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}-1}$$
This was simple enough to just write down. For the last step we have:
$$\frac{\sqrt{45}}{3}=\sqrt{x}$$
$$\frac{45}{9}=5$$
NB That was relatively simple so I can't claim any credit, the OP had the idea which may be original.

Comment: Not to take anything away from the OP's nice  construction, which I think could not be any simpler, but the written history of the golden ratio goes back about 25 centuries, maybe more, so it's likely that somebody found this  construction already.

Comment: yes @user254665!  i have been looking for the construct or something similar!  please, if anyone sees it anywhere (or something similar), please do let me know!  :)  i have checked many major websites/books on the golden ratio, and have been performing image searches on "golden ratio construct" "Golden section construct" etc.  thanks!

Comment: @AstrophysicsMath      I have not seen before the way you constructed.  Another variation I proposed                  [PythagorasCostrn4GR][1]

  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797612/pythagorean-triplet-triangle-associated-with-golden-ratio-construction?lq=1

Comment: wikipedia---golden ratio--- gives 3 constructions  with diagrams, one of which is this one. There may be more in the references.

Comment: @user254665 are you talking to Narasimham 2?  Please share the exact diagram you are talking about.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm talking to the proposer .please see the article in wikipedia, sub-section Constructions,for the diagrams.

Comment: @user254665 i cannot find what you are talking about.  could you please (i ask again) could you please, please link to the diagram you are referring to?  Please?

Comment: @user254665 why do you claim things to exist that do not exist?

Comment: ??? I.m looking at the article  again and see 3 simple constructions  for it with diagrams . Section 4. Mathematics. Geometry. Dividing a line segment by interior division. Dividing a line segment by exterior division. and further down,Odom's construction. Google golden ratio and click on the wikipedia article!

Comment: @user254665 now you are telling us to look at "three different constructions with diagrams."  again more misdirection.  you misleadingly stated that my above construction already exists on wikipedia.  then you refused to provide a simple link.  now you start saying that "there are three constructions. and further down there is odom's construction."  yes we are all aware that there are many constructions for the golden section!  the point here is that you are failing to provide an example backing up what you stated regarding a construction similar to mine. it's not there as you falsely claim.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to construct the golden ratio is to construct two
perpendicular segments joined at endpoints, 
whose lengths are in the ratio $2:1$
like the segments $AC$ and $AD$ in the figure in the question.
One then constructs the segment connecting the other two ends of
these segments to form a right triangle
(whose hypotenuse is $CD$ in the figure in the question).

Finally, one marks off the length of the shorter leg of the triangle
($AD$ in the question, but labeled $BC$ in the figure below) 
on the hypotenuse (at point $E$ in the question, $D$ in the figure below).
The remaining portion of the hypotenuse 
($DE$ in the question, $AD$ in the figure below) has length
$\sqrt5 - 1$ times the length of the shorter leg of the triangle, 
and therefore is in the ratio $\phi : 1$ (the golden ratio) with
the longer leg.

There are examples of this construction at
http://www.goldenmuseum.com/0202geometry_engl.html
and
http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/MATH7200/Sect4.4.html.
A typical diagram of the construction looks like the following 
figure, taken from 
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Construction_of_a_golden_ratio.svg:

[image]

There are a number of ways you can construct the two perpendicular
segments, of which putting two congruent squares side by side
(as in [New Golden Ratio Construction with Two Adjacent Squares and Circle. Have you seen anything similar?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797232/new-golden-ratio-construction-with-two-adjacent-squares-and-circle-have-you-see))
or by setting two congruent tangent circles' centers on a line to
mark the longer leg, and use one of the circles to mark the distance
on the shorter perpendicular leg.

The triangles in the figure in the question and the
figure from Wikimedia are differently oriented (reflected left-right)
and labeled with different letters, but those are unimportant differences.
The main difference between the figures is that in the Wikimedia figure,
the length of the shorter leg is marked off from the end of the
hypotenuse on the shorter leg, whereas in the question that length
is marked off from the end on the longer leg.
If the two legs of the triangle are formed from the edges of two
adjacent squares, as they are in [New Golden Ratio Construction with Two Adjacent Squares and Circle. Have you seen anything similar?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797232/new-golden-ratio-construction-with-two-adjacent-squares-and-circle-have-you-see), then even this difference is not as significant,
since we have two copies of the triangle.

---

**Note:** At this point in the prior-art construction
we have already constructed segment $AD$ so that
$AB : AD$ is the golden ratio. If $BC = 3$ (the radius of the circles in
the question), then $AD$ in the prior-art construction is exactly congruent
to $DE$ in the question. 
If we must have both segments in the ratio lie end-to-end along
the hypotenuse of the triangle, we could simply complete the circle
with center at $C$ and extend segment $AC$ to meet the circle at $F$,
at which point $DF : AD$ is the golden ratio,
and the three-point figure $ADF$ in this construction would be congruent
to the figure $DEF$ in the question.

**Additional Note:** This paragraph is not particularly
relevant to the question, except that it shows a slight advantage to
doing the construction in the "Wikimedia" fashion: namely, after having
*already* constructed the golden ratio once,
we get a "bonus" of constructing a *second* pair of segments in the golden
ratio with merely one action of a collapsible compass.
Namely, we strike an arc with center $A$ from $D$ to $E$,
thereby copying the length of $AD$ onto the long leg of the triangle
dividing the segment $AB$ into
the two parts $AE$ and $EB$, which also are in the ratio $\phi : 1$
(the golden ratio).
To divide the segment $AC$ in the question in this fashion, we have to
construct a point $P$ between $A$ and $C$ such that $CP \cong DE$.
This is easy enough with a non-collapsing compass (use segment $DE$ to
set the compass, then put one end of the compass at $C$ and strike an
arc across the segment $AC$) but rather tedious to do with a
collapsible compass (although that too is a standard classical 
geometric construction).

Comment: Thanks @DavidK !  In my construct and figure above, how would you go about dividing the hypotenuse in the golden ratio as done in the figure you present?  How would you go about dividing the longer leg into the golden ratio in my figure and construct above, as done in your figure from wikipedia?  I do not believe this is a trivial manner, and thus that the constructs, while both incorporating a right triangle/right angle, are very different.  Many constructs incorporate right angles, but are very different.  Thanks! :)

Comment: while both my construct and the wikipedia construct incorporate right angles, the constructs appear to be completely different.

Comment: whereas the golden ratio is constructed in the long leg of the triangle in the example you provide: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/MATH7200/Sect4.4.html, the golden ratio in my construct is given in neither the longer leg of the triangle nor the hypotenuse, but along the segment FD, where the point E is at the golden cut of the segment FD.  I asked you to please show how you would establish the golden cut on the longer leg of the triangle in my construct, but you have not done this.  This is not a trivial matter.  Ergo they are very different constructs. :)

Comment: i'm studying it over and over.  i have seen the common right-triangle construct.  my approach is very different as it does not find the golden ratio in the longer leg of any triangle, but rather along the segment FD, where the point E is at the golden cut of the segment FD.  if they were similar constructs, you would be able to easily find PHI in the longer leg of the triangle in my construct.  but you refuse to do so, as it is not a trivial matter, as the constructs are very, very different.  :)  they both use lines and arcs, but many constructs do :)

Comment: Dear @David K, if you were really serious you would SHOW how you could get the wikipedia construct with the golden ratio in the longer leg of the triangle from my construct.  You say, "and yes, that is slightly harder to do in your construction."  It seems it is impossibly hard as you refuse to do it.  You can't just wave your hands and say, "they both use lines and arcs and thus are the same construct."  They are very different constructs.  If they were similar, you would draw a simple figure marrying them.  But you know this is impossible. Any figure you draw will show the stark differences.

Comment: the reason you are not drawing your idea is because you know how ridiculously cumbersome, cluttered, messy, and complicated it would look.  The constructs are very, very different.  The constructs you presented find the golden ratio along the longer leg of a right triangle.  The construct I present finds the golden ratio not within a triangle, but along the segment DF, which is cut by a circle at point E, at the golden cut.  To get from this to your constructs is a messy, unwieldy process, which is why you REFUSE to draw your contentions, as the resulting mess would further prove me right. :)

Comment: if the constructs were similar in any sense, you would have been able to quickly draw a simple figure connecting them by now.  but they are very different constructs, so you are unable to draw a simple figure connecting them. :)  i seek education and enlightenment, so i would truly welcome a simple figure illustrating your thoughts.  but i think you know it would be a non-trivial mess, and anything but simple, if even possible.  :)

Comment: to anyone reading this, @DavidK deleted all his comments here, while refusing to provide any drawing demonstrating his contentions. :)  the constructs are obviously very, very different. He saw a right angle in both constructs and was off to the races, declaring them to be the "exact same thing."  But then, after failing to explain how they were the same or even similar, he also failed to provide any drawing or figure mapping one to the other, as they are very different constructs.  In the end, after waving his hands around a bit, he found his hasty contention to be impossible in reality.

Comment: I have updated the answer to clarify some points. If I did not believe the answer was justified, I would have deleted it.

Comment: so are you saying that the reason you deleted your above comments is that you did not believe they were justified?  at any rate, thanks for adding the following to your "answer" above: "Additional Note: This paragraph is not particularly relevant to the question,"

Comment: What we're all looking for from you is a simple figure showing how your wikipedia construction is similar to my construction, as you falsely contend.  You know such a figure is not possible to draw, and so you refuse to draw one. :) My construction is motivated in a completely different manner.  My construction begins with two circles and a simple line.  My construction is not centered upon a triangle as yours is.  The construct I present finds the golden ratio not on the leg of a triangle, but along the segment DF, which is cut by a circle at point E, at the golden cut.

Comment: @AstrophysicsMath The "not particularly relevant" is because you were apparently getting distracted by non-essential points. The part above the horizontal line is really all that is needed, the rest is just additional commentary.

Comment: the constructs are obviously very, very different.You saw a right angle in both constructs and were off to the races, declaring the constructs to be the "exact same thing." But then, after failing to explain how they were the same or even similar, you failed to provide any drawing or figure mapping one to the other, as they are very different constructs. In the end, after waving your hands around a bit, you found his hasty contention to be impossible in reality.  So now you keep waving your hands, saying "trust me i cannot show you but i know they are the same as they both use lines."

Comment: DavidK you now admit that you are wrong, backtracking and writing above to Vadim that my golden ratio construct is indeed a unique, original construct.  under the original posting and question you write: "@vadim123 I think you are right. Actually, both may be of interest. – David K"

Comment: @AstrophysicsMath You should delete most of these comments - it's just a one person debate! Also, priority is not as big a deal as you think. [Marjorie Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marjorie_Rice) was a hobbyist.

Comment: @selfawareuser the only reason it looks like a one person debate is because David K deleted all his own comments.  My comments will stay so that he doesn't come back and waste more of everyone's time.

Comment: thanks @selfawareuser ! i think i have found priority on another golden ratio construct which i just posted.  please enjoy it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798843/new-very-simple-golden-ratio-construction-incorporating-a-triangle-square-and